# The plural of "conch"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, pronunciation

There is a lengthy thread on the pronunciation of "conch" however I am curious about the plural form "conches."  I've noticed that it can be found as "conchs" as well, but "conches" appears to be the prevailing spelling in British usage at least.  Insofar as it ends in *-es* it would imply a second syllable which would lend itself to the softer "ch" sound.

Any opinions?

Comment: What did your dictionary tell you? Why is what it said insufficient?

Answer (score 6):

If you pronounce "conch" to rhyme with "honk", the plural is "conchs". If you pronounce "conch" as a near-rhyme with "launch", the plural is "conches".

For how to pronounce "conch", see this question on the [pronunciation of conch](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/proper-official-pronunciation-of-conch) (they're both used, depending on where you live).

Comment: I actually have /kɑŋk/ or /kɑntʃ/ for *conch*, but /lɔːntʃ/ for *launch*, so those two are too far apart for me to consider them “near rhymes”. Perhaps if I said /kɒŋk/ or /kɒntʃ/, I might, since I don’t find /ɒ/ vs /ɔː/ to be phonemic for me.  But /a/ is just too far from  /ɔː/ for it to count, at least in my ear.

Comment: @tchrist: I pronounce them the same way as you, but /ɑ/ and /ɔ/ somehow count as near-rhymes for me, undoubtedly because I've heard so many people with the *cot-caught* merger (I spent 9 years in California).

Comment: I bet that’s it.  I’ve never lived there, just visited scores of times. But even so the Californian form of the *cot–caught* merger always throws me for a loop.

Comment: "lunch" would be closer than "launch"

Answer (score 5):

The plural would be based on the pronunciation. As many dictionaries list two pronunciations (e.g., [Dictionary.Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conch?s=t)), two different plurals are allowed. If you accept the pronunciation of "kongk" your plural would be a matter of a simple -s (*conchs*, pronounced "kongks"). If you say the word with the "ch" sound (as in "CHew") your plural will be *conches*, of two syllables.

Comment: Any references would be very helpful.

Comment: the dictionary site linked to has both pronunciations and both plurals

Answer (score 5):

[According to ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conch), the (British) plural of *conch* is either *conchs* (`/kɒŋks/`) or *conches* (`/kɒntʃɪz/`). The [American equivalents](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/conch) are listed as *conchs* (`/kɑŋks/`, `/kɒŋks/`, or `/kɔːŋks/`) or *conches* (`/ˈkɑntʃɨz/`, `/ˈkɒntʃɨz/`, or `/ˈkɔːntʃɨz/`). Similarly, [Webster states](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conch) that its plural can be either *conchs* or *conches*.

I had no idea that there were people in the world who pronounce *conch* as `/kɒŋk/`, and I expect that those who do, pluralise it as *conchs* (`/kɒŋks/`) and those who don’t, pluralise it as *conches* (`/ˈkɒntʃɨz/`). Going by the dictionary entries, the variants appear to be prevalent on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Could you please rewrite those to use IPA? It is pretty meaningless as written.

Comment: ...or at least in the same pronunciation standard? It looks like Americans pronounce the spelling "-nk" very differently in AmE and BrE, /NGk/ vs /ŋk/.

Comment: @Mitch I am completely certain that no native speaker of English, whether American or otherwise, ***ever*** uses /[N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_nasal)[G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_stop)/ for /[ŋ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal)/.  I suppose I can be in a centralized /[ä](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel)/ but that is phonetic not phonemic. And I have no idea what the heck /ô/ is supposed to mean: it appears to be [illegal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Diacritics).

Comment: @tchrist Updated. Please check my changes as my IPA foo is rudimentary at best.

Comment: +1 for the great references. I'd like to know if it then becomes necessary to pronounce *conchs* with a hard sound and *conches* with the alternate sound. Can we find a source to cite directly for this (i.e., not by implication)?

Comment: @coleopterist Ok, I touched up your IPA for what I think you meant.

Comment: @Kris None of the dictionaries I've checked have entries where the IPA for _conchs_ is along the lines of `/kɑntʃs/` or `/kɒŋkɪz/` for _conches_.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve always used *conches*, pronounced with a hard initial *c* (`/k/`) and a soft *ch* (`/tʃ/`) at the end.

But I also think that spelling it *conchs* and pronouncing it with with hard initial *c* (`/k/`) and hard *ch* (`/k/`) at the end is also acceptable.

Which you use I think depends on which side of the pond you’re from!